# Android: trying to get response when person clicks on a item in list box

Tags: android

I'm just learning how to use ListViews.  I got it working, but wont to be able to respond when some one clicks a item.

I'm trying to use the setOnItemClickListener method to take a call back for when a item is clicked on.  But my code will not compile due to errors in method setOnItemClickListener
r
 Right now i get a error that says 
setOnItemClickListener is not applicable for arguments   OnItemClickListener();

```
void SetUpList()
        {

             listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
             String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile"}; 
             EventsAdapter adapter = new EventsAdapter(this, cGlobals.eventsTitle);

             // Assign adapter to ListView
             listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

    // this is whare I get the error listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

                        }
                    });
            }
    }
```

Comment: please post exact error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have imported this class:

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
```

Next you need to call `setOnItemClickListener()` like so:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override // "@Override" is required for Java 1.6, but forbidden in 1.5
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Do Something
    }
});
```

Or if your activity implements `OnItemClickListener`: You need to add the `onItemClick()` method outside your `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Do Something
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Do something else
}
```

(Of course, if you are extending a ListActivity or ListFragment you should override `onListItemClick()` instead of `onItemClick()` like the second approach.)